# Regex for parsing gift card codes

Tags: regex, parsing

I'm looking to parse gift card codes from a few files. This is an example code:

```
AQ9N-VLL9A3-23FF
```

Basically all alphanumeric characters, in sets of 4, then 6, then 4 again.

Can I come up with a regex expression for parsing this?

Comment: Are you expecting this to be on its own line, or embedded with other text? Always uppercase? What else is in the files that might be false positives?

Comment: Not necessarily on its own line, always uppertext, will be surrounded by spaces and newlines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/35

Or if you know it will be surrounded by `spaces and newlines`

```
(?<=\s+)[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{6}-[A-Z0-9]{4}(?=\s+)
```